# PyQGis animate layer symbology change using thread failed

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt, animation

I need to animate the symbology change over a number of steps in a stand-alone PyQt application that uses qgis.core as library for map, my setup is very similar to [Animating objects on canvas to change color by delay using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201137), it actually runs, but the map failed to change and it also gives the following messages:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QgsFeatureId'
(Make sure 'QgsFeatureId' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QgsChangedAttributesMap'
(Make sure 'QgsChangedAttributesMap' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

so it turns out that the above message was due to I am updating the value attribute of feature via

```
layer.startEditing()
layer.commitChange()
```

So, I switch to use data provider to update, now the messages are gone, but it still not changing the map symbology.

Comment: i think u should show us more precisely the code u're using and where the error is generated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use the dataProvider to update the value of features and not to use the startEditing() and commitChange()